# .htaccess URL rewriting adivce - remove text from url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how to redirect the following with `.htaccess` file, i tried & i figured out to write rule for redirect each url, but how to write a common rule.

need to remove the text "article" form the URL,

examples:

`zzz.com/article/a/b` to `zzz.com/a/b`

`zzz.com/article/g/h` to `zzz.com/g/h`

`zzz.com/article/c/v` to `zzz.com/c/v`

Comment: Please read about [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?zzz\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^article/(.*) /$1 [L,NC]
```

**PS:** If you want external redirection then use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?zzz\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^article/(.*) /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: thanks for your code. but after adding it to htaccess. nothing got changed. how can i debug this?

Comment: Do you have any .htaccess under article dir?

Comment: their is no folder with name article

Comment: Do you want URL in browser to change as well? If yes then you will need additional `R` flag also (see edit).

Comment: You're welcome, glad that worked out.